# Tours of opium poppy farms or processing facilities in Tasmania

Tags: australia, tours, drugs, tasmania

I read several years ago that Tasmania is a [major supplier of legal opiate products](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/as.html), and this weekend I spotted first-hand some farms growing opium poppies.

Are there any tours of opium poppy farms or opium processing facilities available in Tasmania?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasmanian Alkaloids offers (or at least used to, I can't find up to date information) a "[Beyond Farm Gate Tour](http://www.farmpoint.tas.gov.au/farmpoint.nsf/v-events/EB91A50A70AD78F5CA257391000D7CD6)".

I'd suggest contacting them or the Northern Midlands Women in Agriculture Discussion Group who ran the tour, as they may have contacts for such a tour.